# Does intuitionistic negation of A mean that there does not exist a proof of A?

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

Section 13 of Kleene's *Intoduction to Metamathematics* introduces briefly Brouwer's informal intuitionistic school of thought.  There he writes that the interpretation of *not A* is meant to be taken as *A implies a contradiction*.

> From this definition, is it wrong to also interpret *not A* as *there does not exist a proof of A*?

If this were the case I would better understand the non-acceptance of double negation elimination.  Because then, *not not A* asserts that there doesn't exist a disproof of A however, from only that assertion we cannot construct an existential proof of A.

Answer (score 3):

It is not the same. The [semantics of intuitionistic logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/proof-theoretic-semantics/#InfIntAntRea) is proof theoretic, so A → B is interpreted as "given a proof of A a proof of B can be constructed". Then A → F means a contradiction can be derived given a proof of A, i.e. a disproof of A can be constructed. The double negation elimination is blocked because a proof of F from ¬A does not give us a (constructive) proof of A. The law of excluded middle is blocked because we may not be able to prove either A → F or ¬A → F, A may be undecidable. See [Can one prove by contraposition in intuitionistic logic? on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/838184/152568) for more insight.

That there does not exist a proof of A is much weaker than its negation. [Negation as failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_as_failure) to find a proof is used in some automated proof systems, like Prolog, as a pragmatic backstop.